# TYPO3 - Link to filelist folders in TCA

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, typo3-11.x

I didn't find any solution for that, so maybe there is a trick to it? I'm trying something like the selectTree-Feature (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/selectTree.html) just for filelist folders. It doesn't need to be a checkbox, I don't care about the optic, I just need a filelist folder to be selectable in a TYPO3-Record. I hope there is a solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use "type=input" with a renderType="inputLink" to render a "folder" selector (it is possible to limit the view to just show folders).

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know you can limit that!